# npm ENOENT error in installing package

Tags: node.js, bash

I was installing an encryption package for node when I received this ENOENT error.

```
$ npm install crypto2
C:\Users\adity
`-- crypto2@0.3.1
  `-- node-rsa@0.4.2
    `-- asn1@0.2.3

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\adity\package.json'
npm WARN adity No description
npm WARN adity No repository field.
npm WARN adity No README data
npm WARN adity No license field.
```

As for looking in the path the error describes, I looked there and found an old version. I did an uninstall from npm (which also received the same error). Then I had to manually remove it and empty from the trash. 
I also tried to install it globally, again, to no success.

I am using git bash command prompt for this, and tried the same thing with node.js command prompt with it returning the same errors. The package I'm installing is (if this will be any help) :  https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto2

EDIT: I just discovered this problem isn't just with the encryption package but any package that I try to install. When I tried installing Requirejs, same error. This is weird, because I installed a couple of packages yesterday (Passport.js) which installed perfectly without any hiccups whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

It's just warning you that it didn't find a package.json. If you don't have one or need one, then you can just ignore it.

If you want to create one and add the dependencies to it automatically, you could do:

`npm install crypto2 --save`

Comment: I did that but it throws another error saying 'crypto2' is not in the npm registry along with a bunch of errors.

Comment: You should post those in your question then.